# XSLT Transformation in databricks to get the value based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL programming and trying to perform the below transformation where i'll have to fetch the value based on a text value in other attribute/tag

Source XML:

```
<ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
    <ns1:specificationSectionFoodOtherLabellingCopySection>
        <ns1:claimOrStatement>
            <ns1:parameterisedEntity>
                <ns2:code>NUTRITION_CLAIMS_104</ns2:code>
                <ns2:localeData>
                    <ns1:description>
                        <![CDATA[Health Star Rating DI/Claims {l}]]>
                    </ns1:description>
                    <ns1:id>16601</ns1:id>
                </ns2:localeData>
            <ns1:packCopyText>Health Star Rating DI/Claims HSR - Test 72339</ns1:packCopyText>
            <ns1:useOnPackText>Back - Follow Brand Style Guide</ns1:useOnPackText>
            <ns1:statement>Health Star Rating DI/Claims  HSR - Test 72339</ns1:statement>
        </ns1:claimOrStatement>
        <ns1:claimOrStatement>
            <ns1:parameterisedEntity>
                <ns2:code>NUTRITION_CLAIMS_35</ns2:code>
                <ns2:localeData>
                    <ns1:description>
                        <![CDATA[Health Star Rating {s}]]>
                    </ns1:description>
                <ns1:packCopyText>Health Star Rating Better - 72339</ns1:packCopyText>
            <ns1:useOnPackText>Front - Follow Brand Style Guide</ns1:useOnPackText>
            <ns1:statement>Health Star Rating  Better - 72339</ns1:statement>
        </ns1:claimOrStatement>
        <ns1:claimOrStatement>
            <ns1:parameterisedEntity>
                <ns2:code>NUTRITION_CLAIMS_258</ns2:code>
                <ns2:localeData>
                    <ns1:description>
                        <![CDATA[Potassium contributes to normal functioning of the nervous system]]>
                    </ns1:description>
                    <ns1:id>18193</ns1:id>
                </ns2:localeData>
            <ns1:packCopyText>Potassium contributes to normal functioning of the nervous system</ns1:packCopyText>
            <ns1:useOnPackText>Back - Follow Brand Style Guide</ns1:useOnPackText>
            <ns1:statement>Potassium contributes to normal functioning of the nervous system</ns1:statement>
        </ns1:claimOrStatement>
```

XSLT File

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/full" xmlns:ns2="http://www.micros.com/creations/core/domain/dto/v1p0/simple" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns1">
    <xsl:template match="health-star-rating">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'DI/Claims')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ItemDetails>
            <SourceSystem>
                <xsl:text>Fusion</xsl:text>
            </SourceSystem>
            <ActionType>
                <xsl:text>Create</xsl:text>
            </ActionType>
            <CreateDateTime>
                <xsl:text>2021-11-10T08:00:00</xsl:text>
            </CreateDateTime>
            <Items>
                <Item>
                <HealthStarRating>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:specificationSectionDetail/ns1:specificationSectionFoodOtherLabellingCopySection/ns1:claimOrStatement/ns1:packCopyText"/>
                </HealthStarRating>
                <HealthStarRatingDIClaims>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:specificationSectionDetail/ns1:specificationSectionFoodOtherLabellingCopySection/ns1:claimOrStatement/ns1:packCopyText"/>
                </HealthStarRatingDIClaims>
                </Item>
            </Items>
        </ItemDetails>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transformed XML should look like below

```
<HealthStarRating>Health Star Rating Better - 72339</HealthStarRating>
<HealthStarRatingDIClaims>Health Star Rating DI/Claims HSR - Test 72339</HealthStarRatingDIClaims>
<Nutritions>
   <Instruction>
       Potassium contributes to normal functioning of the nervous system
    </Instruction>
</Nutritions>
```

Basically the XSLT should include a condition that determines the value of "description" tag and fetch the value of "Text" tag and outputs as a separate attributes

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve]. Currently your XML is cut off in the middle and includes many elements that are irrelevant to the problem. In general, you want to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to resolve cross-references. P.S. There are no attributes in the shown output.

Comment: Source XML is way too big to post here, but have added the content which is actually requried to be traversed to fetch the value. All the requried tag comes under  <ns1:claimOrStatement>, so not sure if i have to add for-each and then check if that contains the required value

Comment: No one wants to see your entire source XML On the contrary, post a minimal, but complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following XSLT-1.0 template.

In a first step it extracts the "description" without spaces and stores it in a variable.
In the second step it checks whether the description is one of the specific types or an `<Others>`. If it's a specific type, it derives the element name from the description.

```
<xsl:template match="claims">
    <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="translate(entity/description,' &#xa;&#xd;','')" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$elemName='HealthStar' or $elemName='DIClaims'">
            <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Text)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Others><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Text)" /></Others>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your response. though your answer works on the data that i had provided, it isn't working for the ones above(Updated the Question) which is the actual one. The output is as desired but the Condition check is something that requires a change. do i Need to include a for-each statement to fetch the Description as i have to verify each of the description

Comment: I'm sorry. I answered your question as it is. You totally changed the question - and also provided an invalid XML - which has many errors. I won't provide a different answer, because if you liked to have an answer to the current question, you would have asked it it in the first place. So accept this one, and ask a well-thought _new_ question.

Comment: Thanks,i changed my code accordingly with the help of your answer. So the issue is now resolved. Have accepted your answer. Thanks again!